# Graph Isomorphisms, Delaunay Triangulation on a sphere, and Kulikowski's Theorem

Tags: geometry, general-topology, graph-theory, spherical-geometry, polyhedra

Suppose I have a collection of $n$ non-collinear points on a sphere, $\left\lbrace P_i\right\rbrace_{i=1}^n $.  And I construct a mapping from this collection of points to the [Delaunay Triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) on the sphere, $\left\lbrace P_i\right\rbrace_{i=1}^n \overset{DT}{\mapsto} \left( \left\lbrace P_i\right\rbrace_{i=1}^n, \mathcal{F}_{\left\lbrace P_i\right\rbrace_{i=1}^n} , \mathcal{E}_{\left\lbrace P_i\right\rbrace_{i=1}^n}\right) $, where

- $\left\lbrace P_i\right\rbrace_{i=1}^n$ is the set of vertices in the delaunay triangulation.
- $\mathcal{F}_{\left\lbrace P_i\right\rbrace_{i=1}^n}$ is the set of faces (lets just say the faces are the interior regions only) on the sphere.
- $\mathcal{E}_{\left\lbrace P_i\right\rbrace_{i=1}^n} $ is the set of edges.  Edges are really arc segments on the sphere.

To illustrate the point, here is an example of such a Delaunay triangulation:
[image: http://hal.inria.fr/docs/00/44/19/38/PDF/RR-7004.pdf]

[Kulikowski's Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KulikowskisTheorem.html) states, "For every positive integer, $n$, there exists a sphere which has exactly $n$ lattice points on its surface."

So lets call these $n$ lattice points, $\left\lbrace L_i\right\rbrace_{i=1}^n$ and corresponding Delaunay Triangulation mapping as such $\left\lbrace L_i\right\rbrace_{i=1}^n \overset{DT}{\mapsto} \left( \left\lbrace L_i\right\rbrace_{i=1}^n, \mathcal{F}_{\left\lbrace L_i\right\rbrace_{i=1}^n} , \mathcal{E}_{\left\lbrace L_i\right\rbrace_{i=1}^n}\right) $

So, I have some questions, and they are in descending ordered in which I desire an answer for:

- Is there a graph isomorphism from $\left( \left\lbrace P_i\right\rbrace_{i=1}^n, \mathcal{F}_{\left\lbrace P_i\right\rbrace_{i=1}^n} , \mathcal{E}_{\left\lbrace P_i\right\rbrace_{i=1}^n}\right) $ to $\left( \left\lbrace L_i\right\rbrace_{i=1}^n, \mathcal{F}_{\left\lbrace L_i\right\rbrace_{i=1}^n} , \mathcal{E}_{\left\lbrace L_i\right\rbrace_{i=1}^n}\right) $?  If so, does it preserve the (Face-Edge) relationships between the graphs?
- If a graph isomorphism exists, is there a way to explicitly define the graph isomorphic mappings?
- What is the basis for this lattice on the sphere for Kulikowski's Theorem?  Is it any arbitrary basis?

I'm not really sure how to cite the image.  I got it from this paper: http://hal.inria.fr/docs/00/44/19/38/PDF/RR-7004.pdf

Comment: I'm wondering if this question is more catered to the mathoverflow. Yay? Nay?  If not, then which community could best guide me to some answers?

Comment: Okay, I thought about the lattice sphere for a little bit.

 1. There are 3 types of faces on the sphere.  Because I don't know the basis of the lattice, I assume $\left\lbrace l_1, l_2, l_3 \right\rbrace $ is a basis and that  there can be three distinct angles that can be formed, the angle between $l_1$ and $l_2$, the angle between $l_2$ and $l_3$, and the angle between $l_1$ and $l_3$.  We construct the equivalence classes of $\mathcal{F}_{\left\lbrace L_i\right\rbrace_{i=1}^n }$ determined by these distinct angles formed.  Also, I can think of the lattice points as vertices of a polyhedron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your first question is no: no Delaunay triangulation exists for the $n$ lattice points on the sphere from Kulikowski's Theorem, because all $n$ are collinear. (All the points lie in the $x,y$-plane, with the equations as given at Mathworld.  The sphere is just constructed so that the circle where it intersects with the $x,y$-plane is the [Schinzel Circle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SchinzelCircle.html) with $n$ lattice points, and the rest of it has no lattice points.)

The answer to your third question is that it is, by default, the integer lattice (of all points $(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $a, b, c \in \mathbb{Z}$.)  But by applying a linear transformation to get to any lattice you like, you get ellipses (in the plane) or ellipsoids (in 3-space) with the same property; if your lattice has an orthonormal basis, then you'll get spheres again.